# Gradient of Kronecker product in the form of $y^\top (X \otimes I_N)^{-1} y$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Consider the following scalar-valued function of a matrix $X$:

$$
f(X) = y^\top (X \otimes I_N)^{-1} y,
$$
where $y$ is a column vector, $X$ is positive definite and has dimension $L$, and $I_N$ is an identity matrix of dimension $N$.

The question is to compute the gradient of $f(X)$ over $X$. (This is a follow-up question of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3989222/gradient-of-trace-of-kronecker-product/3989399#3989399))

I did not find an explicit formula in [matrix cookbook](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ebonner/courses/2007s/csc411/papers/matrix%20cookbook.pdf). Then I tried to look for the chain rule for matrix derivatives, but the chain rule in (17-19) of [matrix cookbook](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ebonner/courses/2007s/csc411/papers/matrix%20cookbook.pdf) is not explicitly stated in a full matrix form, I think.

Comment: Write this as $$f(X)= \mathrm{tr}[(X \otimes I_N)^{-1} B]$$ where $B= yy^\top$ and apply the answer to your previous question.

Comment: Thanks! This solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use a colon as a convenient product notation for the trace
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = B:A$$
and the well known relationships
$$\eqalign{
(X\otimes I)^{-1} &= (X^{-1}\otimes I) \\
{\rm vec}(ABC) &= (C^T\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(B) \\
A:B &= {\rm vec}(A):{\rm vec}(B) \\
dX^{-1} &= -X^{-1}dX\,X^{-1}\\
{\rm vec}(Y) &= y \quad\iff\quad Y={\rm unvec}(y) \\
}$$
Then you can write the function and calculate its gradient as follows
$$\eqalign{
f &= y^T(X\otimes I)^{-1}y \\
 &= y:(X^{-1}\otimes I)\,y \\
 &= y:{\rm vec}(YX^{-T}) \\
 &= Y:YX^{-T} \\
 &= Y^TY:X^{-1} \\
\\
df &= -Y^TY:X^{-1}dX\,X^{-1} \\
 &= -X^{-T}Y^TYX^{-T}:dX \\
\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= -X^{-T}Y^TYX^{-T} \\
}$$

Comment: In case you missed the post referenced in the comment on the question, we can obtain the following equivalent expression for the derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = X^{-T} \operatorname{tr}_2(yy^T) X^{-T},
$$
where $\operatorname{tr}_2$ denotes a partial trace.

Comment: Question about notation: I've always written $\operatorname{vec}^{-1}$ for the "unvectorization" operation. Is there a context in which "unvec" is standard?

Comment: Oops! I hadn't yet read the previous question.  I've seen the ${\rm vec}^{-1}$ notation before, but I don't think either is standard.  I prefer ${\rm unvec}$ for the same reason that I prefer ${\rm asin}(x)$ to $\sin^{-1}(x)$, i.e. the ambiguity of the reciprocal vs the inverse of a function.

Comment: That's a good point about the notation. Anyway, I think that your answer gives an interesting perspective on how to "interpret" $y$ in this context.